# How to copy element text from one location to another in HTML?

Tags: mootools

I have an element as below

```
<div id="menu">
<dl>
<dt>Features</dt>
<dd>
... Menu elements
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

I need to copy the word `$$(#menu dt")` aka Features into another location after h1 where it is like

w4 ... h1 ...Features

Also I need to add a class to this new element.

I tried using

```
$$("#menu dt").inject($$("#w4 h1")[0],'after');
```

It does copy the element and put to the new location. However, I also lose the old element, aka the old element vanishes. I just want to copy not move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text with `el.get('text');` and then add that to `'w4 h1'` with a setter. Something like:

```
$$("#menu dt").each(function (el) {
    var text = el.get('text');
    document.getElement('w4 h1').set('html', text);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/09tvfjdj/1/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your Mootools version but there are appendText and appendHTML functions availables: http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element#Element:appendHTML